# Trying to synchronize my table in mysql Model with my database and I am getting this error

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

I imported my csv file into SQL ModeL. and now I am trying to synchronize it with database but I am getting this error.

ERROR: Error 1115: Unknown character set: 'DEFAULT'
What does mean 'DEFAULT' in this case

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1115: Unknown character set: 'DEFAULT'
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Leads`.`amocrm_leads` (
          `Название сделки` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NOT NULL,
          `Компания` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Основной контакт` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Компания контакта` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Ответственный` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Этап сделки` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Воронка` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Бюджет` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Дата создания` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Кем создана` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Дата изменения` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Кем изменена` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
         ......
    ,,,,,,,,

SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your columns already support the null values, you dont need to specify the claude DEFAULT NULL, you can delete this "DEFAULT NULL" in all rows. hope it helps!!